# Continue while loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Below is my code for continue while loop. I'm getting the correct o/p after passing the continue statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
i = 0
while i <= 6:
    i += 1
    if i == 3:
        continue
    print i
```

O/p:

```
1
2
4
5
6
7
```

my confusion is while i<=6, so o/p should be 1,2,4,5,6. how its going for the next interation, 7 is greater than 6 ?

Comment: `while i <= 6` This condition is only checked at the _top_ of the loop.  If `i` becomes 7 during the body of the loop, the loop does not magically stop.

Comment: You can move `i += 1` to the bottom of the loop, to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is only checked at the start of each iteration.

It checks `6 <= 6`, which is `True`, then increments `i` to `7`, then checks if `7 == 3`, which is `False`, then prints `7`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with continue. You are printing after `i+=1`. So, if iteration starting when i=6 is the last one, then in that same iteration, i becomes i=7 after `i+=1`, and is printed as is

```py
i=0
while i<=6:
   i+=1
   print(i)
```

also displays 1 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have incremented 'i' before executing the other operations in the loop.
Therefore when `i=6` you enter the loop for the last time, increase it by one, and then print `7`